# Place object exactly in the middle of a surface

Tags: objects, faces

I am trying to modify a microlattice for uni. I have the structure on the right, I  want to have spikes on all the cylinders of the structure distributed evenly. Like I did on the left with copy and past, but distributed symmetrically throughout out the hole structure. When using snapping, I can not make sure that the spikes are exactly in the middle. And using a mirror, I still have problems placing them on the inner cylinders. [image: I have the Struture on the right, I want want to have spikes on all cylinders of the strucure]
How I can place them evenly throughout all cylinders?

Comment: What is the topology of your lattice-cell? i.e What information do you have available? Or even better, share your model on https://pasteall.org/blend/